# VirCurEx - Balance vs Available Balance

Tags: transactions, client, exchanges, buy-bitcoins, hosting

So I have a VirCurEx account and I moved 1.5 BitCoins over to it... After the transaction was complete (like a day ago) I was checking and the website said "Balance - 1.5" which is correct but then for Available Balance it said "Available Balance - 0.74900001" or something close to that.

So I trade half of my bit coins in for other currencies (PPCoins, NameCoins, LiteCoins, etc.) and when I tried to trade more it wouldn't let me... Even though I have about .76 BitCoins left in the account (and I can withdrawal them if I want) the Available balance says 0.0001 (or something close to that, I'm not looking at it now)

Does anyone know what the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out I had placed an order to sell half of my bit coins a while back and forgot about it... the order was still in effect thus rendering half of my stock unusable hahaha! All is well now!